# Running a flask server

Tags: python, flask

So, probably a dumb question, but I am beginning to learn all this so your feedback will be valuable for me.

The question is: In [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) documentation it says start the flask server by entering the command 'python hello.py' and I do it successfully to see the output on localhost:5000. Now, I have a shared hosting plan and if I upload this file over there will i need to initiate the server over there as well like this? If so, when I close the terminal over there, will the flask server shut down (because when I close the terminal on my computer it shuts down the flask server and the results are no more available on localhost:5000)?.. It basically suggests me that I have to keep running the terminal all the time..please tell me what is the basic idea here? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what your exact task is, but completely independent of your question, in case you don't know, flask takes a synchronous approach.  If you want something that is asynchronous, consider [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/).  Not saying that flask or synchronous approaches don't have their place, they obviously do, it's just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is how you deploy your app. There are many options, that will depend on your needs, your hosting service, etc.

You should check the flask docs for the options. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/

In essence, you'll have your flask app running as a local service on the server, so it's not shut down when you close the terminal, and an HTTP server that somehow proxies requests to that service. I guess the most popular is uWSGI with nginx.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload your code to a remote host, you will need to provide a way to start the server and get things running. How this works is host- and software-dependent. As an example, here is some [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#deploy-your-application-to-heroku) for how you would fire Flask up on Heroku.