# Keep running a python flask app in linux

Tags: python, linux, putty

This is something similar to this post
[Running a flask server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19739189/running-a-flask-server). I wanted to check if there is any other option other than deploying the flask app to keep it running for debugging purpose.

I work on a python program hosted in linux server. The program uses flask as it is a web based application. I am connecting to the linux server using `putty` progaram in Windows. So i run the program using `python mainprogram.py` in putty and i can view the application is running and can be opened in the browser.

But the application gets closed when putty is closed. How can i keep the application running even after i close putty. below is the URL set for the app

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, threaded=True, debug=True)
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/396654/how-to-run-the-python-program-in-the-background-in-ubuntu-machine might help.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975624/how-to-run-a-python-script-in-the-background-even-after-i-logout-ssh) is what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks !! this command worked.    "nohup python mainprogram.py & "

Comment: a program called [GNU screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) will keep the python session going even if you disconnect